# Subadditivity of square root function

Tags: inequality, radicals

Any hint to prove

$$ \sqrt{x+y} \le \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}, \qquad \forall x,y \ge 0 $$

Comment: Simply square both sides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $$\sqrt{x+y}\le \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\Leftrightarrow x+y\le x+y+2\sqrt{xy}.$$

Which clearly holds as $x,y\ge{0}$, and the function $x\rightarrow x^2$ is monotonic and equality occurs when one of $x$ or $y$ is $0$.

Comment: So, assuming the result that you want to prove, you are able to show something that is clearly true. (I hope you see the problem.)

Comment: This would be correct if you replaced  $\implies$ with $\iff$ (and, perhaps, pointed out that the equivalence is true because $x \mapsto x^2$ is strictly monotone increasing, and thus order-preserving, for non-negative real $x$).

Answer (score 6):

Another:

$x,y \geq 0$ then the product $\sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}$ have sence and now
$$\sqrt{x + y} \leq \sqrt{x + 2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y} + y} = \sqrt{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2} = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$$

Answer (score 4):

I'll try the hard way
and use calculus.

Let
$f(y)
= \sqrt{x+y} - \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}
$.

$f(0)
=0
$.

$f'(y)
=\frac1{2\sqrt{x+y}}-\frac1{2\sqrt{y}}
$.
Since
$x+y \ge y$,
$\sqrt{x+y} \ge \sqrt{y}$
so
$\frac1{2\sqrt{x+y}}
\le \frac1{2\sqrt{y}}
$.

Therefore
$f'(y) \le 0$
for all $y$.

Since
$f(0) = 0$,
$f(y)
\le 0
$ for all $y$.

Note that this
can be used to show that
if
$g(y)$
is increasing and
$g'(y)$
is decreasing
then
$g(x+y)
\le g(x)+g(y)
$.

Similarly,
if $g'(y)$
is increasing,
$g(x+y)
\ge g(x)+g(y)
$.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is homogeneous, hence we may assume $y=1$ without loss of generality.

So we just have to prove that $\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}\leq 1$, pretty easy:
$$ \sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x} = \frac{(x+1)-x}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\leq 1.$$

Comment: May I ask what it means for an inequality to be homogeneous?

Comment: @Khallil: that if we replace $x$ and $y$ respectively by $\lambda x$ and $\lambda y$ (with $\lambda > 0$) the inequality is unchanged.