# Is there a one-word term for "grows by square root"?

Tags: terminology

We can describe a growth relationship $y = x$ as *linear* (e.g. "linear growth").

We can describe $y = \log(x)$ as *logarithmic* (e.g. "logarithmic growth").

We can describe $y = x^2$ as *quadratic* (e.g. "quadratic growth").

We can describe $y = 2^x$ as *exponential* (e.g. "exponential growth").

Is there a one-word term to describe a growth relationship where $y = \sqrt{x}$ ?

The best suggestion I've seen is "radical growth", which does not seem to be a standard term and I think would cause confusion if used without explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asymptotic growth of a root is known as *"sublinear growth"*. Another term is *"fractional-power"* growth but it sounds odd imo.

The *sublinear* term originates from linear algerba. It can be used not only for square-root but for any $n-th$ root complexity.

In strict terms as sublinear function is a function that satisfies the following properties:

- **Positive Homogeneity:** $f(kx) = k^n f(x) \quad n\in\mathbb{R^+_0}$ and
- **Subadditivity:** $f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$

Roots satisfy both. The proof of positive homogeneity is trivial. As far as the proof of subadditivity is concerned you can check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588776/subadditivity-of-square-root-function)

Other seemingly sublinear functions (such as log) do not satisfy these properties therefore, in a sense you can separate them from sublinears.

Comment: My impression is that the term "sublinear" is also applicable to logarithmic growth; is that correct? I am hoping for a term that clearly distinguishes the growth as separate from logarithmic growth.

Comment: @Kevin I edited my answer, to answer to your comment

Comment: Roots do not satisfy "Positive Homogeneity".

Comment: @BrianO $f(kx) = \sqrt k f(x)$ with degree of homogeneity $= \frac12 > 0$. e.g  $\sqrt{kx} = \sqrt k \sqrt x$

Comment: @BrianO I edited my answer so its clearer.

Comment: This can be generalized for n-th roots too btw

Answer (score -1):

Well since $y=\sqrt x \implies y^2=x$, I would call it inverse quadratic growth, i.e. the inverse of the function has quadratic growth.

Comment: We can also write it as $ y = x ^ {1/2} $ and call it "fractional quadratic growth", but that doesn't seem right either.